# Subclasses in Parse for Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

Within Parse when you setup a new user, their password is hidden. Is there a way to do this? I am creating an application that stores my login information for multiple websites.

I was looking into creating a subclass, but if I do setPassword(pass); will that show hidden in the backend of Parse?

If not, is there a way to do this when doing a ParseObject?

Comment: There is no way to view password field in parse, it is encrypted. Though you can change password. What you can do is create new field for password, like mypassword and save password there.

Comment: Im not looking to view the password. I'm looking to create a field that will be encrpted. For example, if I have a pin field. I don't want that pin to be displayed in the backend

Comment: Another example. If I create an app that has a username and password login, but the app is something that stores my username and passwords for other stuff (like bank cards, websites, etc) I would that info in a separate class than the User class. But I want the string to be hidden in the backend